Exercise about identity regarding a function in Schwartz space which Fourier coefficients are Fourier transforms of another function
The following is a simple yet challenging exercise about Fourier transforms. It is part of an older exam for my undergrad course in Elements of Functional Analysis. The professor usually comes up with his own exercises, so I didn't bother looking for solutions in books. However, I couldn't manage to find anything similar on here either, so I figured it's best to ask a new question.
Let $f\in S(\mathbb{R})$, where $S(\mathbb{R})$ is the Schwartz space (space of all smooth and rapidly decreasing functions). Then let $g$ be defined as follows:
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f(x+n)
$$
The first question is to show $g$ periodic with period $T=1$, which is trivial. For the second task, the problem defines $\hat{g}_n$ as the Fourier coefficients of $g$ on the Fourier base $u_n(x)=e^{i2\pi n x}$ and $\hat{f}$ the Fourier transform of $f$. It is asked to show that:
$$
\hat{g}_n=\hat{f}(2\pi n)
$$
This isn't a tough proof. Let $(\,|\,)$ be the internal product in $\mathcal{H}\supset S(\mathbb{R})$. Then:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{g}_n &= (u_n|g) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-i2\pi n x} g(x) dx \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-i2\pi n x} \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x+k) dx \\
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i2\pi n (y-k)} f(y) dy \\
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i2\pi n y} e^{i2\pi n k} f(y) dy \\
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{i2\pi n k} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i2\pi n y} f(y) dy \\
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{i2\pi n k} \hat{f}(2\pi n)
\end{align}
$$
where I used $y=x+k$ by substitution.
What now? I reckon from Euler's identity that $e^{i2\pi n k}$ should be equal to $1$, since $e^{i2\pi n k}=(1)^{nk}=1$, but I'm not sure. And what about the sum over $\mathbb{Z}$?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Check the definition of Fourier coefficients. $g$ is $1$-periodic, hence $\widehat{g}_n= \int_0^1 ...$, not $\widehat{g}n= \int\mathbb{R} ...$.

You need to show $$\hat{g}n=\int\limits{-\frac12}^{\frac12} g(x), e^{-i 2 \pi n x}, dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x), e^{-i 2 \pi nx}, dx=\hat{f}(2 \pi n)\tag{1}$$ where $$g(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(x+n)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat{g}_n, e^{i 2 \pi n x}\tag{2}$$ and $f\in S(\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks, it was (of course) surprisingly simple all along.
